# php regular expression html - the last occurence behind the end match

Tags: php, html, string

Trying analyze a webpage
https://www.zap.co.il/model.aspx?modelid=593364

(which compare same product price on different stores - each store has a block with it's logo, price...)

i want to seperate each store to a different array element with: preg_match_all

I want somehow to skip the advertisers area (the stores at the top - in this example the two first stores)

as i see - each element starts with:

```
<div class="StoreLine">
```

ends with (only elements that are not advertizements)

```
<div class="SmartBuyButtons">
```

or

```
<div class="BuyButtons">
```

I use this expression:

```
preg_match_all("/<div\sclass=\"StoreLine\">*.*?(<div\sclass=\"SmartBuyButtons\">|<div\sclass=\"BuyButtons\">)/s",$str,$zapElements);
```

which works fine, however i dont know how to skip the the advertisers area
which those elements also begins with

```
<div class="StoreLine">
```

So somehow i need the last occurence behind the end match

Comment: Don't use RegEx to parse HTML, they don't work well with nested expressions. Use a proper parser instead, such as php simple HTML DOM parser

Answer (score 0):

finally i just cut the string to have only the text that appears after the advertisement:

```
$str = strstr($str, '<div class="SortBy">');
```

Comment: This would be the way to go.